# ListView - mouse over row: how to show element to overlap next row?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a custom button (the pencil image) which on mouse over shows the "Rename" box, but in my listview is enlarging the current row (so that both pencil image and Rename box fit inside the row height)

What should I use to make it look like the image attached?

[image]

Comment: you're sure , it is not a ToolTip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is [ToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx). you can customize the your `ToolTip` to look like that.

if that is not `ToolTip`, you have to use [Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx).